# SimpleXML load file under certain conditions

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm using SimpleXML to load a bounch of files from a directory. All files has the same structure, with different values, you can think at them like xml receipt.
What I would like to achive is to load the file and display the content based on a particular value, let's say the customer name. I'm doing like this:

```
$files = glob('../my_directory/*.xml');

$customerName = $_GET['customer_name'];

foreach ($files as $value) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($value);
    echo"
        <tr>
            <td>" .$xml->Header->Transmission->CustomerName. "</td>
            // and so on......................
        </tr>
    ";
}
```

Everything works fine, but, as I said, I'm traiyng to display the content based on the value `$customerName` and display all the data for that value. I googoled a lot, but I didn't find any help. I tried something like

```
 if ($xml->Header->Transmission->CustomerName === $customerName) {
      // do something
 }
```

but is not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was giving up, but  I managed to solve the problem in this way (hope this could help someone else):

```
// select the directory with xml files
$files = glob('../my_directory/*.xml');

// define the data I need 
$customer_name = $_GET['customer_name'];

// load the files
foreach ($files as $value) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($value);

    // define the variable with the data I want to check
    $CustomerName = $xml->Header->Transmission->CustomerName;

    // check for the correspondence
    foreach ($CustomerName as $name) {
        if ($name === $customer_name ) {
            echo"
                <tr>
                    <td>" .$xml->Header->Transmission->CustomerName. "</td>
                    // do my stuff here ......................
                </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
}
```